# Purple textures

Tags: modeling, rendering

So I am working on a project and I just rendered it and it was purple. This only happened after I appended a set of objects into the project. The custom object I made rendered completely fine before I added these new ones in. I checked the files to make sure textures were linked to the right place and all of them are. I checked my mapping on all the objects and they're all correct. I even went to undo everything to before I appended the objects in and its still dark purple color. Everything else I've tried to do from what I have seen in other posts with similar questions hasn't worked.

Comment: If _everything_ including the background is purple, it's probably a problem with your world shader.  Are you using an HDRI?  If so, Blender is probably not able to find it on disk.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The hdri looks fine, it’s only the objects that are purple

Comment: Unlikely, but have you checked if there is something missing? (*File > External Data > Report Missing Files*)

Comment: Yes I have, everything was there and it all should’ve been working. I’ve been told that it’s a big that can Occur when appending assets into blender but Idk how true that is.